# Wifi not working after a short time with RTL8723BE, not able to switch to other network before restart

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP 15-r204TX. When I start Ubuntu Wifi works fine but after 2-3 mins the browser shows no internet connection. Turning WiFi off and back on doesn't fix it and I'm not able to switch networks - it shows "connecting" and never gets connected. If I restart, it works again for 2-3 minutes.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands, one line at a time in the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

**What it will do?** The `11n_disable` option disables 802.11n features. Adding it to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` makes the change persist after reboots (because it will be part of the module config). The `modprobe -rfv` commands are removing the kernel modules `iwldvm` and `iwlwifi`, and finally the last line `modprobe -v` is adding `iwlwifi` back in.

To know what those kernel modules are/do, you can run `modinfo <module name> | grep description`, which will tell you the following:

`iwlwifi` is an Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux (generic Intel drivers)

`iwldvm` is Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux (more specific drivers)